# Batch Gradient descent algorithm showing 'int' not iterable error

Tags: python, machine-learning, gradient-descent

```
lr = 0.1
n_iterations = 1000
m = 5

theta = np.array([[1000],[989],[123],[3455]])

for iterations in n_iterations:
    gradients = 2/m * X_b.T.dot(X_b.dot(theta) - y)
    theta = theta - lr * gradients
    
theta
```

After executing the code it says an error 'int' is not iterable.

More data:

```
X_b = np.asanyarray(df[['area', 'bedrooms', 'age']])
```

from a csv file

and Im using the three params(area,bedrooms,age) to predict the price i.e y

Please help me in that error

Comment: Can you show me what's error is showing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`n_iterations` is an int, which is not iterable like the error says. I think you want to loop `n_iterations` times.

Try `range` for that like this:

```py
lr = 0.1
n_iterations = 1000
m = 5

theta = np.array([[1000],[989],[123],[3455]])

for iterations in range(n_iterations):
    gradients = 2/m * X_b.T.dot(X_b.dot(theta) - y)
    theta = theta - lr * gradients
    
theta
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `for iterations in n_iterations:` where `n_iterations` is an integer value that shouldn't iterate. You can use range to overcome it

`for iterations in range(n_iterations):`